# Self-binding with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, console-application, simple-injector, constructor-injection

I'm trying to learn dependency injection with Simple Injector so I've created a simple program. I looked through tons of examples, but didn't find anything similar to this. Ninject has a similar example and they self-bind the implementation to itself using

```
Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf();
```

But I didn't find any self-binding examples in simple injector. As it stands the program runs fine and I get expected results I'm looking for, but is it the right way to do it? The program is the last code sample.

Interface

```
public interface ICar
{
    void Move(string direction, int distance);
    void Stop();
}
```

Class

```
public class Driver
{
    private readonly ICar _car = null;

    public Driver(ICar car)
    {
        this._car = car;
    }

    public void Drive(string direction, int distance)
    {
        _car.Move(direction, distance);
    }

    public void Brake()
    {
        _car.Stop();
    }
}
```

Implementations

```
public class Ferrari : ICar
{
    public void Move(string direction, int distance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am driving {0} really fast for {1} miles", direction, distance);
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am slamming on the brakes because I'm going too fast");
    }
}

public class Lexus : ICar
{
    public void Move(string direction, int distance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am driving {0} for {1} miles", direction, distance);
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am applying the brakes");
    }
}
```

Program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;

        container.Register<ICar, Lexus>();
        container.Register<ICar, Ferrari>();

        container.Verify();

        var johnDoeLexus = new Driver(container.GetInstance<Lexus>());

        johnDoeLexus.Drive("North", 10);
        johnDoeLexus.Brake();

        var johnDoeFerrari = new Driver(container.GetInstance<Ferrari>());

        johnDoeFerrari.Drive("North", 10);
        johnDoeFerrari.Brake();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The way to do self-binding in Simple Injector is using the following registration:

```
container.Register<Samurai>();
```

Which is a short-cut for:

```
container.Register<Samurai, Samurai>();
```

Which again is a short-cut for:

```
container.Register<Samurai, Samurai>(Lifestyle.Transient);
```

When calling `Register<TService, TImplementation>`. what you're basically asking the container is to create the `TImplementation` every time a `TService` is requested.

Simple Injector however can resolve concrete types (such as your `Samurai`) without explicit registration, but in most cases it is best to explicitly register all types (or at least all types that you request directly from the container by calling `GetInstance<Something>()`). By registering that type, you let Simple Injector know that you want to resolve it and this allows Simple Injector to verify whether it can be resolved (when calling `Verify()`) and it allows Simple Injector to [diagnostic analysis](https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics) on that type.

Please note though that calling `GetInstance<TService>` will request the registered `TService`. In your code you are doing this:

```
container.Register<ICar, Lexus>();
var johnDoeLexus = new Driver(container.GetInstance<Lexus>());
```

In other words, you are registering an `ICar`, but you are not resolving an `ICar`, you are resolving a `Lexus`. Since `Lexus` hasn't been registered as `TService`, Simple Injector knows nothing about that type, and it will simply create a new registration for you for this `Lexus`. This would be the same as doing this:

```
container.Register<ICar, Lexus>();
container.Register<Lexus, Lexus>();
var johnDoeLexus = new Driver(container.GetInstance<Lexus>());
```

This can be problematic, because perhaps you intended `ICar` to have a different lifestyle:

```
container.Register<ICar, Lexus>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

var instance1 = container.GetInstance<Lexus>();
var instance2 = container.GetInstance<Lexus>();
```

You might expect both calls to `GetInstance` to return the same (single) instance, but this isn't the case, since Simple Injector will create a new (transient) registration for `Lexus`, and a new `Lexus` will be created on each call to `GetInstance`.

Also note your usee of `AllowOverridingRegistrations`. Using `AllowOverridingRegistrations` is most of the time a bad idea. While other containers allow you to register a bunch of types of the same abstraction by calling `Register` multiple times, Simple Injector does not allow this. Instead, Simple Injector contains an `RegisterCollection` method for this. For instance, registering multiple cars can be done as follows:

```
container.RegisterCollection<ICar>(new[] { typeof(Lexus), typeof(Ferrari) });
```

You can request those cars as follows:

```
var cars = container.GetAllInstances<ICar>();
```

Or you can inject a collection of cars into a constructor of a type:

```
public SomeType(IEnumerable<ICar> cars) {
    this.cars = cars;
}
```

If you registered a list of cars however using `RegisterCollection`, requesting a single car using `GetInstance<ICar>` will fail, since Simple Injector does not know which of those cars it should return.

The API is [designed explicitly](https://simpleinjector.org/separate-collections) this way, to make it less likely for developers to make errors in their registrations that still compile and even run, but have incorrect results. Flagging the container with `AllowOverridingRegistrations` allows to replace a made registration. This can be useful in scenarios where the container's configuration is split up into multiple libraries and reused by multiple applications. It overrides a made registration. This means you will loose this previous registration. Most of the time you actually don't want this.

Comment: Thanks Steven for being so thorough. In response to you stating that GetInstance<ICar> will fail because it doesn't know which car to return -- is the design of this application flawed (could there not be multiple implementations, i.e. Lexus, Ferrari)? If so, what would be the correct way to update this example to help me learn how to correctly approach the design of the program? Thanks.

Comment: @mjw06d The code you've shown is just a toy application and there's not much that I can say about that. It's hard to imagine what for useful business behavior this ICar interface would have. It's very hard to demonstrate a valid use of Dependency Injection using cars or samurai warriors. My advice is to try the concepts of DI and SOLID out on a real prototype application you would actually build for your boss (web application with some business logic for instance) and come back to Stackoverflow with questions on the design of that application and the use of dependency injection for that app.

Answer (score 1):

Self-binding is implicit behavior of Simple Injector. Hence, a line like

```
Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf();
```

is simply not necessary with Simple Injector.

Comment: True, but it's advisable to register all (root) types explicitly because this keeps the configuration [verifiable](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How-to#Verify-Configuration) and [diagnosable](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Diagnostics).

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is more *What is the purpose of Ninject's* `.ToSelf()`

Ninject uses `.ToSelf()` as a more readable version of

```
kernel.Bind<Samurai>().To<Samurai>();
```

`.ToSelf()` is less redundant:

```
kernel.Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf();
```

The reason you want to do `.ToSelf()` is so you can continue to chain methods such as defining the scope. Ninjects has implicit self-binding so you don't need `.ToSelf()` unless you are going to define scope or something else:

```
kernel.Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

kernel.Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf().InThreadScope()
```

Simple Injector's api is different, so as Robert Petemeier says, `.ToSelf()` is not necessary:

```
container.Register<Samurai>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

On Dependency Injection:

You are asking for a `Lexus` when you should be asking for an `ICar`:

```
ICar car = container.GetInstance<ICar>()
```

You decide if you want a `Lexus` or `Ferrari` based on which concrete class you register `ICar` as.

[Simple Injector is well documented](https://simpleinjector.org/documentation)